# Can poles of z-transform transfer function be zero to eliminate transient response?

Tags: z-transform

I believe that answer to "Can poles of z-transform transfer function be zero to eliminate transient response?" is no, but I am not sure why it's no.

Answer (score 1):

If all the poles of a system's transfer function are zero (i.e. they lie in the origin of the $z$-plane), then you have a finite impulse response (FIR) system. This implies that the transient response is also of finite length, but it does exist. It depends on the initial condition of the filter, i.e. on what is stored in the delay elements at the time of the transient in the input signal. But also if the initial condition is zero there will be a transient response until the system's memory is filled with the input signal.

Take as an example the step response of a causal FIR system assuming zero initial condition:

$$a[n]=\sum_{k=0}^nh[k]\tag{1}$$

Due to the finite length $N$ of the impulse response $h[k]$, the step response $a[n]$ reaches its final value at $n=N-1$:

$$a[N-1]=a[N]=\ldots =a[\infty]=\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}h[k]$$

For $n<N-1$ we observe the transient response to the unit step at the system's input.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by transient response?
If pole is zero then it acts as low pass filter.
Still you get transient response for transient analysis.
Transient responses is a type of analysis to see the time varying curve